# How to parse array of objects, each object has a dates array, returning a unique dates array and two data arrays

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to come up with a way for format this data.

Desired Return:
An object with 3 arrays

1. a unique array of dates
2. an array of data1 values the same length as the `dates` array, with `null` and the index that corresponds with the index in the `dates` array for which `data1` does not have a value
3. the same as 2, except for data1 values

The example shown below should give a better idea of what I am trying to solve.

Desired Result:

```js
{ dates: ['Tue Jun 20 2018', 
          'Wed Jun 21 2018', 
          'Thu Jun 22 2018',
          'Fri Jun 23 2018',
          'Sat Jun 24 2018'],
  data1: [5, null, 12, null, 20]
  data2: [14, 4, 15, 2, null]
 }
```

Example Input: 
An array with multiple objects.
Each object has a `dates` property

```js
[
  { dates: ['Tue Jun 20 2018',
            'Thu Jun 22 2018',
            'Sat Jun 24 2018'],
    data1: [5, 12, 20]
  },
  { dates: ['Tue Jun 20 2018', 
            'Wed Jun 21 2018', 
            'Thu Jun 22 2018',
            'Fri Jun 23 2018'],
    data2: [14, 4, 15, 2]
  }
 ]
```

I can solve by creating two objects key value pairs for each input object, joining all dates into an array and making unique, mapping over the new dates array and inserting `null` values in each data array if that specific object does not have that date as a key.

Sorry for the long/ confusing explanation. Have a look at the input/ output and let me know how I can best solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shift in new dates by adding `null` to all other rows:

```
 function merge(data, key, { dates = [], values = {} } = {}) {
   // Add the key to the resulting values
   if(!values[key]) values[key] = [];
   // Go over all dates of the data
   for(const [index, date] of data.dates.entries()) {
     // Add new dates by adding `null` to all keys
     if(!dates.includes(date)) {
       dates.push(date);     
       Object.values(values).forEach(arr => arr.push(null));
     }   
     // then copy the value from data to values
     const pos = dates.indexOf(date);
     values[key][pos] = data[key][index];
   }
   // also add a method for chaining
   return { dates, values, result: { dates, ...values }, merge(data, key){ return merge(data, key, this); }, };
}
```

Usable as:

```
 const { result } = 
    merge(arr[0], "data1")
   .merge(arr[1], "data2");
```